# Get sum as an additional column instead of only column

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I'd like to sum up all the order amounts, grouped per user from my database, for a specific set of users.

I'm using [`.sum()`](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-sum) and [`.groupBy()`](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-groupBy) to do this, like so:

```
knex('orders')
  .select(['id_user', 'order_amount'])
  .whereIn('id_user', ['user-foo', 'user-bar'])
  .sum('order_amount')
  .groupBy('id_user')
```

This returns the sums:

```
[ { sum: 500 } ]
[ { sum: 600 } ]
```

But now there's no way to know which sum corresponds to which user.

This would be my ideal result:

```
[ { id_user: 'user-foo', sum: 500 } ]
[ { id_user: 'user-bar', sum: 600 } ]
```

How can I also get the `id_user` column for each sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `knex.raw()` for that:

```
knex.select('id_user', knex.raw('SUM(order_amount)')).from('orders').groupBy('id_user');
```